# Installing "aspace" package in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, spatial, statistical-test

I am trying to install the R package aspace but i get an error message that reads:

```
install.packages("aspace")
# WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently
# installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of
# Rtools before proceeding:
#
# https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
# 
# Installing package into ‘C:/Users/LENOVO/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
# (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) Warning in install.packages :   package
# ‘aspace’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2).
```

Can anyone take me through the steps to install this package using the archived version
from CRAN? I have already downloaded the archived version from
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/aspace/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/aspace/aspace_3.2.tar.gz"`

`install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")`

`library(aspace)`